# gedit color HTML file

Tags: gedit

I have a file that I don't want to put `.html` in its name. However, I still want gedit to color it like an HTML file. Is there a way that I can tell gedit to color it as an HTML file? Like putting some header at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gedit should automatically detect the file as HTML if it begins with a doctype declaration. If you're writing HTML 5, make sure the first line is **`<!DOCTYPE html>`**. Doctype declarations are required anyway...

---

If it does not work, add a comment containing a Vim or Emacs style modeline:

- `<!-- vim: set ft=html: -->`
- `<!-- -*- mode: html -*- -->`

However, this requires the Modelines plugin to be enabled.